# ImageMagick missing decode delegates

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I recently moved to MediaTemple and installed ImageMagick and IMagick following their KB article [here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1778/Is+ImageMagick+installed+on+the+%28gs%29+Grid-Service?#gs).

No error and phpinfo() show module correctly installed.

When I try to use IM on a JPG image via PHP I get this error

```
Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format 
/home/149263/domains/wer.com/html/images/pictures/post/tmp/original/' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544' in /nfs/c10/h04/mnt/149263/domains/wer.com/html/application/controllers/post.php:301
Stack trace:
#0 /nfs/c10/h04/mnt/149263/domains/wer.com/html/application/controllers/post.php(301): Imagick->__construct('/home/149263/do...')
#1 [internal function]: Post->filter('punch')
#2 /nfs/c10/h04/mnt/149263/domains/wer.com/html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /nfs/c10/h04/mnt/149263/domains/wer.com/html/index.php(217): require_once('/nfs/c10/h04/mn...')
#4 {main} thrown in /nfs/c10/h04/mnt/149263/domains/wer.com/html/application/controllers/post.php on line 301
```

However `convert -list configure` returns

```
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jpeg jp2 lcms openexr png rsvg tiff wmf x11 xml zlib
```

and `identify -list format` returns

```
JPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (62)
JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format
```

So it looks like the installation is correct.

```
ImageMagick 6.7.7-0 2012-05-22 
imagick module version  3.1.0RC1
```

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a quick and dirty on installing the latest (version 6.8.4-6 as of this writing) ImageMagick on Ubuntu 12.04.

Start by removing any old versions previously installed via apt-get:

sudo apt-get remove imagemagick

Then update apt-get and install some supporting packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libperl-dev gcc libjpeg-dev libbz2-dev libtiff4-dev libwmf-dev libz-dev libpng12-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev libexif-dev perl libjasper-dev libltdl3-dev graphviz pkg-config
```

Use wget to grab the source from ImageMagick.org.

Once the source is downloaded, uncompress it:

```
tar -xzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

Now configure and make:

```
cd ImageMagick-6.8.4-6
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

To avoid an error such as:

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Update: If you still get an error like the one above, try running ldconfig:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

You can confirm the install and available formats with:

```
identify -list format
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running some code using Imagemagick through exec( ) to see if the problem is with Imagemagick or Imagick?

Comment: argh, bonzo thx for replying - it was my bad, the filename was not being passed correctly to IM and therefore it was crashing - the hint was 2nd line of error log above showing no filename

Comment: Glad its sorted; although IM's error reporting can be confusing sometimes.